# Linux mint - How to reinstall sound drivers

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I used to have many choices about sound/audio hardware:

analogue sterio output

surround sterio output

analogue HDMI sterio output ... etc

[image]

now they seem missiong 
and also virtual box shows the message :

No audio devices could be opened.

obviously there is a problem with the sound drivers. 
I removed everything and re installed pulse and alsa
I even reinstalled the kernel
nothing seems to work

by the way the sound works perfectly but I have these issues:
when using headphones I must each time

use alsamixer to unmute the headphones and increase their volume
and the sound does not go out by HDMI (to the TV monitor)

```
$ inxi -AS
System:    Host: mmmmmm-pc Kernel: 4.4.0-78-generic x86_64 (64 bit)
       Desktop: MATE 1.16.1  Distro: Linux Mint 18.1 Serena
Audio:     Card Intel 7 Series/C210 Series Family High Definition Audio Controller
       driver: snd_hda_intel
       Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.4.0-78-generic
$
```

Comment: In Pulseaudio, many variations are shown via `pavucontrol`, either as profile choices in the *configuration* tab, or as ports in the *output/input devices* tabs. The Linux Mint menu may or may not offer all this choices, in doubt, try `pavucontrol`. Number of channels (stereo vs. surround) is now handled automatically. The huge number of devices you had in ALSA isn't necessary any longer.

Comment: I installed **pavucontrol** i showed the `Connection to PulseAudio failed` error !

Comment: Check with `ps` if Pulseaudio is running. If it's not running, you can start it manually with `pulseaudio --start` (then the question is why it doesn't start automatically). Also do `aplay -l` and edit your question with the output to see if ALSA is working. Additionally, do `aplay -L` to see if ALSA automatically assigns your "missing" devices (though you won't need them under Pulseaudio).

Comment: I removed pulseaudio completely because caused many problems mainly `pulseaudio daemon startup fail` pulse audio volume control unable to connect to pulse audio server...